# Pushing cloned project to new github repository hangs

Tags: git, github

Hello Stackoverflow community,

First, I've searched around the site and have spent this entire week reading up on this issue, but I have not found any solution. I'm hoping someone here can help me. I'm trying to push a cloned project to a new github repository but the process hangs and I have no idea what's wrong.

Goal: to push a cloned github project (cloned from github.com/xyz) to a newly created github repository (which exists in github.com/abc)

Problem: after running "git push origin master" and entering my username and password, the process just hangs (no errors of any kind)

The steps I took (which worked several times earlier this year, but no longer does for some unknown reason):

1. created new repository on github.com/abc (my personal acct)

#### Terminal:

1. `git clone <https://github.com/xyz/project.git>`
   (xyz is school acct that contains the project that I want to clone and push to abc)
2. `cd into cloned project`
3. `git init` (msg says "Reinitialized existing Git repository in...")
4. `git add` . (i run git status and this shows "nothing to commit" msg)
5. `git commit -m "msg"`
6. `git remote set-url origin <https://github.com/abc/project.git>` (origin previously points to xyz as expected, but this cmd successfully changes origin's ref to abc)
7. `git push origin master`

As stated above, I ran through these steps exactly as listed several times earlier this year and it worked all the time. But now, it no longer does. It just hangs on me after step 8. What's going on?

I've also tried to remove the old origin reference in order to run "git remote add origin new-remote-repo-URL":

1. `git remote rm origin` (successfully removes origin)
2. `git remote add origin new-remote-repo-URL` (successfully adds new origin)

Relacing step 6 with these two steps and then running step 7 also hangs.

Thanks for reading. Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try using `GIT_TRACE=2 GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git push origin master` to get debug output from git and SSH.

Comment: After step 3, try and delete the .git folder. Then do step 4.

Comment: I had something similar few days ago - im using github for few years and it was the first time i had it, i opened a ticket in git hub and they "fixed" it. They had error on their side and you cant know it yourself. so if its still not working and it does work on other repos contact them

Comment: VonC: I removed .git folder then did step 4) & up. Step 4 shows "Initialized empty Git repo..."; i ran step 5, then did git status & it showed all files in the cloned project (which is great!); step 6 worked & running git log showed the commit I just made;  step b successfully added new origin; finally step 8... still hangs :(

I took your advice and did this twice, first using the existing cloned project, then when this didn't work, deleting the clone and going through all the steps again from a fresh start (while remembering to remove the .git folder prior to step 4). nada. Thanks though :)

Comment: Aasmund Eldhuset: I tried that and it spit out some stuff I couldn't understand, then it hanged on me as well ====> trace: run_command: 'send-pack' '--stateless-rpc' '--helper-status' '--thin' 'https://github.com/abc/project.git/' 'refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master'
trace: exec: 'git' 'send-pack' '--stateless-rpc' '--helper-status' '--thin' 'https://github.com/abc/project.git/' 'refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master'
trace: built-in: git 'send-pack' '--stateless-rpc' '--helper-status' '--thin' 'https://github.com/abc/project.git/' 'refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master', etc...

Comment: codeWizard: this link ===> github.com/wp-e-commerce/WP-e-Commerce/wiki/… doesn't actually tell me how to create a ticket. How do I do that? I googled "how to open ticket on github" and that was the closest thing I could find. It was not helpful, however. Also, thank you so much for helping me edit my original post. I'm relatively new to stackoverflow and am not familiar with formatting the content.

Comment: Have you tried using the ssh URLs instead of https?

Comment: hi onionjake; thx for the response, but no, i did not try using ssh urls; the next best thing was to follow codeWizard's suggestion to open up a ticket on github, but i couldn't figure out how to do that; searched and searched but found nothing; not even on github site itself; i've since moved on from that little 'mini' project; it was a waste of my time and i could not figure out a solution;